# gnupg decrypt python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, gnupg

New to python and programming.  Currently writing a little python 3 code to keep my Bank Account login details etc.  I've had it working by opening and closing a file and using the out='filename' for gnupg module, however ideally i'd like it to write to a memory as I don't want the decrypted info on the disk if I can avoid it.

The file is created by another function in the program, which pickles a dictionary and encrypts it to a file.  However when I try to decrypt and open it with this:

```
def OpenDictionary():
    """ open the dictionary file """
    if os.path.isfile(SAVEFILE):
        f = open(SAVEFILE, 'rb')
        print('opening gpg file')
        buf = io.BytesIO()
        decrypted_data = gpg.decrypt_file(f, passphrase=PASSWORD)
        buf.write(decrypted_data.data)
        print ('ok: ', decrypted_data.ok)
        print ('status: ', decrypted_data.status)
        print ('stderr: ', decrypted_data.stderr)
        f.close()
        dictionary = pickle.load(buf)
        buf.close()
        return dictionary
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Josh Harney\Dropbox\Python-pys\gpg-banks.py", line 179, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])   File "C:\Users\Josh Harney\Dropbox\Python-pys\gpg-banks.py", line 173, in main
    dictionary = OpenDictionary()   File "C:\Users\Josh Harney\Dropbox\Python-pys\gpg-banks.py", line 87, in OpenDictionary
    dictionary = pickle.load(buf) EOFError
```

Same result on my Linux box.  I've tried a bunch of stuff to make this work, no luck so far.  Can anyone suggest a better way to do this?  Basically I need to get the gpg.decrypt_file to output to a buffer or variable, and pickle.load to read it back to dictionary.

Comment: Just based on the documentation to `python-gnupg`, you should use [`str(decrypted_data)`](http://packages.python.org/python-gnupg/#decryption) instead of `decrypted_data.data`. Also, you can just use [`pickle.loads`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.loads) to convert the string to an object directly, rather than going through a `BytesIO` object. (And you can use [`pickle.dumps`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps) on the encrypting end.) Hopefully the decrease in complexity will fix whatever problem is happening here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  If I do that, switching to stringIO for the buffer, and str(gpg.decrypt_file(f, passphrase=PASSWORD)) i get:TypeError: '_io.StringIO' does not support the buffer interface.  I think the gpg.decrypt_file returns object Crypt, hence being able to use attribute types .ok, .status and .stderr  as well as .data.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood. Drop all the pseudo-files (StringIO and BytesIO) completely; you don't need them. Use `pickle.dumps` to generate a string; encrypt the string using `gpg.encrypt`, save the encrypted string to a file. Then load the encrypted file into a string, decrypt it to a string (using `str(gpg.decrypt(data))`) and pass that string to `pickle.loads`. No `StringIO`/`BytesIO` objects involved at all.

Comment: If you're just wanting to play with Python, by all means, continue; however, if you're really doing this to make it easy to save and retrieve private data like bank acct info, I would suggest looking for a gpg frontend that's already out there. You might enjoy [pyrite](https://github.com/ryran/pyrite).

Comment: @ryran, Yeah i'm just playing about with python for the moment!  I'll look at pyrite though, it looks interesting.  I've rewritten the two functions for strings, still no luck.

Comment: and:    def OpenDictionary():
    """ open the dictionary file """
    if os.path.isfile(SAVEFILE):
        f = open(SAVEFILE, 'r')
        enc_data = f.read()
        print(enc_data)
        print('opening gpg file')
        decrypted_data = gpg.decrypt(enc_data, passphrase=PASSWORD)
        print ('ok: ', decrypted_data.ok)
        print ('status: ', decrypted_data.status)
        print ('stderr: ', decrypted_data.stderr)
        f.close()
        print(str(decrypted_data.data))
        dictionary = pickle.loads(decrypted_data.data)
        return dictionary

Comment: now works.  Thankyou @senderle for a steer in the right direction.

Comment: def SaveDictionary(dictionary): savestr = pickle.dumps(dictionary) status = gpg.encrypt(savestr, recipients=['my@email']) if status.ok == True: print('scrap buffer') f = open(SAVEFILE, 'w') f.write(str(status)) f.close() else: print('Something went wrong with the save!!!') print ('ok: ', status.ok) print ('status: ', status.status) print ('stderr: ', status.stderr)

Answer (score 0):

```
def OpenDictionary():
""" open the dictionary file """
try:
    if os.path.isfile(SAVEFILE):
        f = open(SAVEFILE, 'r')
        enc_data = f.read()
        print('opening gpg file')
        decrypted_data = gpg.decrypt(enc_data, passphrase=PASSWORD)
        print ('ok: ', decrypted_data.ok)
        print ('status: ', decrypted_data.status)
        print ('stderr: ', decrypted_data.stderr)
        f.close()
        dictionary = pickle.loads(decrypted_data.data)
        return dictionary
except Exception as e:
    print('Something Snaggy happened in the call OpenDictionary(), it looks like: ', e)


def SaveDictionary(dictionary):
    savestr = pickle.dumps(dictionary)
    status = gpg.encrypt(savestr, recipients=['my@email'])
    if status.ok == True:
        print('scrap buffer')
        f = open(SAVEFILE, 'w')
        f.write(str(status))
        f.close()
    else:
        print('Something went wrong with the save!!!')

    print ('ok: ', status.ok)
    print ('status: ', status.status)
    print ('stderr: ', status.stderr)
```

with thanks to @senderle